# Having trouble with printing mutated variable outside function (Python)

Tags: python

```
def satisfiesF(L):
"""
Assumes L is a list of strings
Assume function f is already defined for you and it maps a string to a Boolean
Mutates L such that it contains all of the strings, s, originally in L such
        that f(s) returns True, and no other elements
Returns the length of L after mutation
"""
result = []
for l in L:
    result.extend(l)
L = list(result)
for i in result:
    if i != 'a':
        L.remove(i)
return len(L)
```

Basically what I am trying to do is mutate the list, L within the function. From my testing, it appears that the end result of L is exactly what I am looking for it to be, but when I print L outside of the function it just spits out the original, unmutated list. Can anyone help me fix this issue?

disclaimer: This is a homework problem, but I'm not looking for a solution to the whole problem - just this one issue. Thanks!

Comment: What course is this question from?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham MITx: 6.00.1x Introduction to Computer Science and Programming Using Python through edX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing the name `L` to point to a new list inside the function, in line -

```
L = list(result)
```

This does not change the list outside the function, because only the local variable `L` changed to point to a new list, its previous reference was not changed (And the name/variable outside the function, that was used to call this function still points to the old list).

You should iterate over copy of result (created using `result[:]`)  and remove from result , without changing the reference `L` points to. And then at end use `L[:] = result` , to make changes to the list reference that `L` points to.

Example -

```
list1 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
def satisfiesF(L):
    result = []
    for l in L:
        result.extend(l)
    for i in result[:]:
        if i != 'a':
            result.remove(i)
    L[:] = result
    return len(L)
satisfiesF(list1)
>>> 1
list1
>>> ['a']
```

Comment: Hi Anand, the reason I iterated over result was because I can't seem to get the correct answer if I have an instance where there is a list within a list (such as ['a', 'b', 'c', ['a', 'b', 'c']]) to produce the correct answer. with the removal of the "L = list(result) line, I receive an error when trying to remove from the nested list.

Comment: Try that latest code now.

Comment: Thank you Anand! So, just to get this straight, using L[:] = result allows the global variable L to be changed from inside the function whereas L = result does not?

Comment: Its like this, in python , everything is pass by reference, when you call the function passing the list as argument, L points to the reference of the passed in list, but as soon as you do `L = <something else>` , the reference changes to something new, that does not cause the passed in global variables' reference to change. When you do `L[:] = something` it changes the list in place, this does not cause L to become a new reference, instead its still the old reference, just the elements inside it change.

Answer (score 0):

```
def satisfiesF(L):
        temp=L[:]
        for x in temp:
            if f(x)!=True:
                L.remove(x)
        return len(L) 
def f(s):
    return 'a' in s
```

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
result = []
for l in L:
    result.extend(l)
```

with

```
result =L[:]
```